# Screenshot is saving to SD card but is just black pixels

Tags: java, android

I am trying to grab a screenshot and save to the SD card. The file is created and is about15kb but is just a rectangle of black.
Any idea where I am going wrong?
The following code is called inside my surfaceview class.
w & h were previously saved.

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "test.jpg";
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
this.draw(canvas);
OutputStream fout = null;
File imageFile;
imageFile = new File(mPath);
try {
fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fout);
fout.flush();
fout.close();
}
```

Comment: `ARGB` is `RGB` and `Alpha`. `Alpha` is not supported on `JPG` images, and when saving it gets automatically converted to black. So if you are drawing some black shape on the image, be aware that the background will also be black (and not transparent), so you'll see a black picture. Save it as `PNG` instead, or use a `RGB` configuration

Comment: try ` Bitmap.Config.RGB_565`

Comment: Thanks guys - tried that but still the same

Comment: @carpman Please update the question, include the latest code you tried

Comment: Sorry - new to this and not sure how to do as you ask but will do my best! - done (I think!)

Comment: Also tried as PNG but will same result :(